# libxml or libxml2

Tags: xml, embedded

I want to use an xml parser which will be run on an embedded system.

Which one should I use, libxml or libxml2?

What are the benefits of each regarding embedded systems?

Answer (score 1):

As written in [libxml2 FAQ](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html), you should only go with libxml if you have backward compatibility concerns. Therefore, I advise to go with libxml2 which is

> known to be very portable